# «Você» e «Sr(a)» são equivalentes? Podem ser usados em substituição um do outro?

Tags: significado, pronomes, frases

«Você» e «Sr(a)» são equivalentes?

Podemos usar você em substituição de Sr(a)?

E existem diferenças no seu uso nos diferentes países de língua portuguesa?

Exemplos:

> O Sr. está bom?
>
> Você está bom?

Comment: No Brasil, podes sempre substituir "você" por "Sr.(a)", mesmo que fique cômico chamar uma criança de 10 por "Sr.". Quando usar "Sr.(a)"? Varia bastante entre regiões, pessoas e idade do falante e do audiente. Eu provavelmente não trataria uma pessoa de 90 anos por "você" se a não conhecesse, assim como uma pessoa considerada adulta. Alguém de 15 anos, porém, eu trataria por "você", Algumas pessoas tratariam todo mundo por "você" e outros tratariam por "Sr.(a)" apenas superiores, como chefes.

Comment: Pergunta no meta: https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

São sinônimos, mas não equivalentes, porque o grau de formalidade é diferente.

"Você" é informal; pode ser usado para qualquer pessoa, mas não é polido usar para pessoas de mais idade ou cuja posição social exige outro tratamento. Também depende da situação; o amigo do juiz ou do presidente da república podem usar "você" em conversas privadas e informais, mas não em documentos escritos ou reuniões formais.

"O senhor" é mais formal e é indicado para pessoas mais velhas, desconhecidos, superiores hierárquicos ou pessoas em posição de autoridade, quando não for indicado tratamento ainda mais formal (Vossa Senhoria, Vossa Excelência, Meritíssimo, etc.) Não deve ser usado com crianças, a não ser que a intenção seja sarcástica ou lúdica.

Não sei se há diferenças entre os diversos países lusófonos. Parece-me que os portugueses tendem a ser mais formais que os brasileiros, mas é apenas uma impressão sem maior base científica.

Comment: Você só é informal no Brasil. Em Portugal, informal é a segunda pessoa do singular, e é sempre usada com "tu".

Comment: Concordo com o ANeves. Você, em Portugal, tem uma conotação diferente. E "Você" não é informal em todo o Brasil, No Rio Grande do Sul usa-se a mesma regra de Portugal. O "Você" em Portugal é usado mais quando há uma hierarquia, por isso, muitos portugueses acham estranham pais chamarem filhos por "você"

Comment: @Peixoto No Rio Grande do Sul "você" não é formal; é tratamento dado a estranhos, especialmente quando são mais jovens ou tem posição hierárquica inferior. "Você é para negros", já ouvi dizerem. E isso não vale para todo o RS; nas regiões de colonização alemã ou italiana, segue-se o costume do restante do país - "você" é informal, "tu" não se usa, ou só no registro popular, e com conjugação de 3a pessoa.

Comment: @LuísHenrique morei 18 anos em Santa Cruz do Sul que tem imigração alemã. Só ouvi você em situações formais ou quando precisava falar com alguém de fora do estado.

Answer (score 1):

Sr (a) se refere ao Pronomes de Tratamento ,formalidades,  educação  e respeito a alguém que muitas vezes você não conhece e muito mais a alguém mais velho  que você , o tratamento sempre será diferente ,  como até quando se apresenta a um Juiz,  Advogado e etcs  profissões também  se engloba , esse tratamento é o mais formal possível , como por exemplo  nos Estados Unidos a formalidade é  a mesma no entanto deve se chamar pelo o sobrenome , se você mudar isso será considerado um desrespeito ,   se usa Sr(a) e o sobrenome  da pessoa por educação , principalmente se não o conhece , em outros países também não se muda muita coisa ,são senhor ,senhores,  senhora ou senhoritas  são anciãos um tratamento formal .

Comment: Quando morri asfixiado ao tentar dizer a frase toda... não se pode distribuir uns pontos finais por aí? :)

Answer (score 0):

o termo "senhor" ou "senhora" é geralmente uma forma de respeito com os mais velhos ou com alguém que temos menos afinidade ou não conhecemos, como por exemplo:

Maria esta na fila do banco com sua mãe e percebe que um rapaz passou deixou sua carteira cair, então maria diz ao rapaz: - com licença, esta certeira pertence ao "senhor"?.

já o termo "você" é geralmente mais usado com pessoas que temos mais afinidade, como primos, irmãos, amigos e etc.. exemplo:

João entra em seu quarto para pegar sua mochila, mas como ele não a encontra pergunta a sua irmã Maria se ela pode ajuda-lo. João diz: - Maria, "você" poderia por favor me ajudar a encontrar minha mochila?.

Comment: Aqui utilizamos mais o tu em substituição de você,

Comment: Maria , tu poderias me ajudar.  Neste caso não é comum utilizar o você em Portugal